# Azure mobile services don't want to work

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have problem with Mobile services. I'm using git for working on them, but last few days every change I make, it doesn't run. Like I don't make any changes. I try to change code with web portal, but code is changed, but it's running like not. Every change I see on portal I can pull to local via Git and every change I make local can commit and push to server (and see changes on portal), but my code is running like few day before, without any changes.

What I'm doing wrong? I assume there is some problem with deployment. Please help?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"? What is not running? What kind of code / scripts do you have?

Comment: Yeah I'm struggling to understand the question as well. Can you edit your question to add more detail? Maybe show screenshots of your code? Something?

Comment: Sorry about unclear question/problem. I had problems with azure services, every change I made in code (with portal or git), wasn't recognized when I was testing it. 
On running all changes was ignored and scripts was running as older versions (without any changes I tried to make in 2 days).
But now (after 2 day of breaking thing), all works fine. Obviously was some problem inside Azure, but probably we will never know.

If anyone else will have similar problems, my advice is to take day a break.

Comment: I have seen similar behavior a couple of times. Using the Azure Command-line Tools you can restart your Mobile Service and all should be well. Install tools from http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/ and run 'azure mobile restart <servicename>'.

Comment: thanks, I probably will need that in future.